# How do homonyms impact English Language Learners' comprehension?

Tags: english, orthography, language-acquisition, homonymy

I understand that homonyms are words that sound alike but have different meanings. They may or may not be spelled the same. For example, the word 'fair' is spelled and pronounced the same for three words with three different meanings. We may talk about a girl with a ***fair*** appearance going to see the county `fair`. She paid a ***fair*** price to get into the `fair`. 
I was wondering how does it impact English Language Learners' comprehension?

Comment: Not quite. "Homophone" is the term for words that sound alike but have different meanings. "Homonym" is a broader or even ambiguous term that can cover both "homophone" and "homograph". For this reason linguists often avoid it.

Comment: They don't impact it often. They haven't bothered the native speakers, who ignore them. Since they're usually used in different contexts, nobody notices any contrast. An EL learner may learn one and be confused to encounter it with a different meaning, but we're all familiar with words that have similar sounds; it's just another word to learn, that's all. Though it does make for strange meaning associations in the mind; I will always associate cooking with sewing in Mexican Spanish, for instance, because of _coser_ and _cocer_, even though most of the individual verb forms are distinct.

Comment: Thank you hippie trail and jlawler for responding!! It was very helpful.

Comment: It might be useful to have an answer here. Someone care to post one?